# Mysql XA Isolation Level

Tags: mysql, serializable, acid, xa

Does anyone know why Mysql requires serializable isolation level to achieve ACID properties with XA transactions or what would be lost if you used repeatable read and XA?

> However, for a distributed
>   transaction, you must use the
>   SERIALIZABLE isolation level to
>   achieve ACID properties. It is enough
>   to use REPEATABLE READ for a
>   nondistributed transaction, but not
>   for a distributed transaction.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/xa.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe it has to do with the nature of `REPEATABLE READ` and the limitations of XA in the mysql engine (MySQL is not fully compliant with the XA spec).

A known issue is that certain crash scenarios with replication can cause a transaction to be absent from the binlog: [From: Restrictions on XA Transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/xa-restrictions.html)

With the above, Consistency in ACID is lost.

I assume that the strict behavior forced by `SERIALIZABLE` mitigates this to the extent required with how they describe the xid etc. working. But elaboration on these issues is suspiciously absent.  [Mysql 5.6 - Consistent Read](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-consistent-read.html)